# enviar texto de imagen ocr a un input por post php

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

Estoy extrayendo un numero de imagen, para ello estoy usando tesseract. Necesito enviar el texto extraído a un input para que sea almacenado en la bd.
Lo estoy haciendo por `$_POST` pero el error que me refleja es `Undefined array key "codvivienda 123200422"` El codigo que recibo "123200422" es el texto de la foto ocr

```
<form method="POST" action="./src/newregistro.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cod.Vivienda:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control " id="codvivienda" name="codvivienda[]" maxlength="5" >
   <input type="file" class="form-control " id="image" name="image" required>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Registrarse</button>
</form>
```

El archivo php donde proceso el formulario

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$typeImage = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$comando = "tesseract " . escapeshellarg($typeImage) . " stdout -l spa -c debug_file=/dev/null";
exec($comando, $textoDetectado, $codigoSalida); 
if ($codigoSalida === 0) {
    $textoComoCadena = join("\n",$textoDetectado);
} else {
    echo "Error detectando texto. Por favor verifique que la imagen existe y que el programa de detección está instalado y es accesible desde PHP. El código de salida es: " . $codigoSalida;
}
$codvivienda = $_POST["codvivienda\n$textoComoCadena"];
$insertar = "INSERT INTO  lecturas (codvivienda, imagen) VALUES 
('$codvivienda','$image')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

if ($resultado){
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Lectura Registrada!");';
    echo 'window.location.href="../registro.php";';
    echo '</script>';
    
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta información en tu pregunta, porque no aparece un campo para seleccionar archivos y, además, pones corchetes en el nombre del campo `codvivienda`. Al tener los corchetes, haces que el campo sea tratado como un arreglo y no tiene sentido hacerlo cuando se trata solo de un elemento.

Al procesar el formulario, vas a recibir en `$_POST` algo como:

```
'codvivienda' => array('Código ingresado'),
'otro-campo' => 'Valor de otro campo'
```

Para acceder a ese único elemento del arreglo, lo haces con el nombre del campo y el índice cero, porque en el formulario solo existe un campo:

```
$codvivienda = $_POST['codvivienda'][0];
```

**Actualización:** De acuerdo a tu último comentario, no necesitas tener el campo `codvivienda`, porque ese dato lo vas a llenar con el texto detectado en la imagen:

```
<form method="POST" action="./src/newregistro.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="form-control " id="image" name="image" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Registrarse</button>
</form>
```

Accede directamente al campo con `$_POST['codvivienda']`:

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$typeImage = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$comando = "tesseract " . escapeshellarg($typeImage) . " stdout -l spa -c debug_file=/dev/null";
exec($comando, $textoDetectado, $codigoSalida); 
if ($codigoSalida === 0) {
    $textoComoCadena = join("\n",$textoDetectado);
} else {
    echo "Error detectando texto. Por favor verifique que la imagen existe y que el programa de detección está instalado y es accesible desde PHP. El código de salida es: " . $codigoSalida;
}
// Solo debes usar el texto detectado
$codvivienda = $textoComoCadena;
$insertar = "INSERT INTO  lecturas (codvivienda, imagen) VALUES 
('$codvivienda','$image')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

if ($resultado){
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Lectura Registrada!");';
    echo 'window.location.href="../registro.php";';
    echo '</script>';
    
    
}
```

Con esto, ya solo te faltaría manejar el error cuando no se pueda detectar texto en la imagen y, tal vez, alguna validación adicional. Por ahora, sería suficiente con hacer la inserción de datos dentro del `if`.

Comment: Hola, disculpa por ser tan poco claro, me falto añadir esa parte, en efecto lo que deseo es que en el input codvivienda vaya el código que fue detectado por la imagen. Edite mi pregunta añadiendo el input de imagen

Comment: @dasmorphy, revisa la respuesta actualizada.